# Windows Authentication with IIS Reverse Proxy and Kestrel Asp.net Core server

Tags: .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I would like to know whether it is possible to use IIS reverse proxy to pass through windows authentication to Kestrel server running self hosted.

Thank you